# object.style.x doesn't return anything

Tags: javascript, css

In JavaScript on my website I have something like this:

```
console.log(document.getElementById("side_news").style.display);
```

and I have tried this with a lot of styles and it doesn't return anything, just blank. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do `console.log(document.getElementById("side_news"))` and see if you get anything other than `null`

Comment: If it were null he'd get an error about not able to access the style property of null.

Comment: `.style` only accesses inline styles, not styles set from CSS files.

Comment: getComputedStyle -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getComputedStyle()`:

```
var sideNewsDiv = document.getElementById('side_news');
getComputedStyle(sideNewsDiv).getPropertyValue("display");
```

**MDN documentation:** [Window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle).

Answer (score 0):

Most elements don't show all of their attributes when accessing through `object.style`. A `div` element has a default display style of `block` but accessing it through `style` will result an empty value.

A solution is to use `getComputedStyle` - or, if not supported by the browser, `currentStyle`.

```
if (window.getComputedStyle)
    status = window.getComputedStyle(targetElement, null);
else
    status = targetElement.currentStyle;
```

This will show the element's style with all the css changes.