# How to check the text-overflow property of a DOM node in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to check whether a DOM node has a CSS property `text-overflow` equal to `ellipsis`. When I try `node.text-overflow` I get the error

> Cannot read property 'text' of undefined

and I've also tried `node.textOverflow`. What should I be checking?

Answer (score 1):

`object.style.property` works to get a property of an object. The property names are lower camel cased. In this case it would be `node.style.textOverflow`

This is useful for setting property values, but not so much for retrieving them. Even if you use the above, you will still get

> Can't read property textOverflow of undefined

This is because most elements don't show all of their attributes when accessed through object.style.

Take a div element for example. It has a default display style of block but accessing it through style will result an empty value.

To display it, we can use `getComputedStyle` along with `getPropertyValue`

It's important to note that this method is not available on IE8 or earlier.

> The Window.getComputedStyle() method gives the values of all the CSS properties of an element after applying the active stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may contain.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

```js
var par = document.getElementById("par");
var overflowStyle = document.getElementById("overflow-style");

var style = getComputedStyle(par).getPropertyValue("text-overflow");

overflowStyle.innerHTML = style;
```

```css
#par {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<p id="par">This is a really long paragraph</p>

<p id="overflow-style"></p>
```

Also, take a look at these Stack Overflow posts

[Get a CSS value with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338217/get-a-css-value-with-javascript)

[object.style.x doesn't return anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23175288/object-style-x-doesnt-return-anything)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are looking to access the CSS property of your node, you need to access it through the style property. Otherwise you had the right idea.

```
if(node.style.textOverflow == "ellipsis")
```

You can find the Javascript syntax for the css property at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp).

Comment: Provide commentary to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

"text-overflow" can't be a variable name (javascript doesn't allow variables with "-" in the name), so maybe try `node.style.textOverflow`?.  Also, if you already have jQuery installed, you may try `$(object).css('text-overflow') === 'ellipsis'`